# PrimeNg Multi Select Not Displaying Any Data

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I just started to learn primeng and I picked up a very simple drop down combo box to practice but things didnt go as expected.

this is my App.Component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
cities: City[];

selectedCityCodes: string[];
constructor() {
this.cities = [
  { name: 'New York', code: 'NY' },
  { name: 'Rome', code: 'RM' },
  { name: 'London', code: 'LDN' },
  { name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST' },
  { name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS' }
];
}
}
interface City {
  name: string,
  code: string
}
```

and here it is App.Component.html

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCityCodes" optionLabel="name" optionValue="code"></p-multiSelect>
```

and just in case you'll need this is app.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {MultiSelectModule} from 'primeng/multiselect';
@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
FormsModule,
MultiSelectModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Output is this:

[image: output image]

as you can see there is no data when i click "down" icon.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. the problem was with the BrowserAnimationsModule

in order to get dropdown menu work properly you will need to first install the BrowserAnimationsModule.

Install it with

```
npm install @angular/animations
```

then include it in your app.module file

```
imports: [
...
BrowserAnimationsModule
```

],

Done. it works...  :)